# How to add -emit-llvm flag to Makefile in Android Kernel project built with Bazel?

Tags: android, makefile, kernel, bazel

I'm working on an Android Kernel project that is built using Bazel. I want to add the -emit-llvm flag to the Makefile in order to generate LLVM Intermediate Representation (IR) for the compiled code. However, I am encountering issues when trying to do so.

When I add the -emit-llvm flag to the Makefile and build the project, I receive the following error message:

```
out/bazel/output_user_root/a19f94e48a7a10a10153b94863fa6bb6/sandbox/linux-sandbox/76/execroot/__main__/common/scripts/check-local-export: llvm-nm failed
Terminated
```

I have tried setting the LLVM variable in the Makefile, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. There are no LLVM-related environment variables in the Bazel sandbox, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's the relevant part of my Makefile:

```
LLVM := /usr/bin/

ifneq ($(LLVM),)
$(info ======================$(LLVM)======)
ifneq ($(filter %/,$(LLVM)),)
LLVM_PREFIX := $(LLVM)
else ifneq ($(filter -%,$(LLVM)),)
LLVM_SUFFIX := $(LLVM)
endif
```

but I get the "======================1======" output.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to correctly add the -emit-llvm flag to the Makefile and resolve the llvm-nm failed error? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `Makefile` snippet in the question is modified compared to the upstream version:

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -448,7 +448,10 @@ HOST_LFS_CFLAGS := $(shell getconf LFS_CFLAGS 2>/dev/null)
 HOST_LFS_LDFLAGS := $(shell getconf LFS_LDFLAGS 2>/dev/null)
 HOST_LFS_LIBS := $(shell getconf LFS_LIBS 2>/dev/null)

+LLVM := /usr/bin/
+
 ifneq ($(LLVM),)
+$(info ======================$(LLVM)======)
 ifneq ($(filter %/,$(LLVM)),)
 LLVM_PREFIX := $(LLVM)
 else ifneq ($(filter -%,$(LLVM)),)
```

The obvious question here is why the `$(info)` output does not contain `/usr/bin` and the answer is that `LLVM=1` is passed as [override](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding) `make` variable when the kernel build is invoked. The definition is in the [build environment setup](https://cs.android.com/android/kernel/superproject/+/ee85bbb6c296676778164782e34b5f2808c1706d:build/kernel/_setup_env.sh;l=212) of the Android kernel build. Hence any attempt to override it in the Makefile will not be successful.

But that was not the **actual question**. It is unlikely that `-emit-llvm` will be made an officially supported flag for the build as it is not really a common use case and the resulting build is not really useful for anything other than inspection. Additionally, one is usually interested in the generated assembly of *one* compilation unit.

With that in mind, we can make use of the fact that the kernel build knows how to build LLVM assembly files when asked to do so as a hack. In order to preserve the output, building with `--config=local` (implicit when `--config=fast` is used) to preserve the intermediate build directory.

So, here it goes:

1. **Override** the `make` goal, e.g. for the `kernel_aarch64` target in the corresponding `BUILD.bazel` file of the `common/` subdirectory:

```
diff --git a/BUILD.bazel b/BUILD.bazel
--- a/BUILD.bazel
+++ b/BUILD.bazel
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@ _GKI_X86_64_MAKE_GOALS = [
 define_common_kernels(target_configs = {
     "kernel_aarch64": {
         "module_implicit_outs": COMMON_GKI_MODULES_LIST,
-        "make_goals": _GKI_AARCH64_MAKE_GOALS,
+        "make_goals": ["kernel/pid.ll"] + _GKI_AARCH64_MAKE_GOALS,
     },
     "kernel_aarch64_16k": {
         "module_implicit_outs": COMMON_GKI_MODULES_LIST,
```

That effectively instructs kbuild to build `kernel/pid.c` with `-emit-llvm` and emit the results into `kernel/pid.ll` in addition to the usual goals.

2. **Run** the actual kernel build:

```bash
$ tools/bazel build --config=fast //common:kernel_aarch64
```

3. **Locate** the `pid.ll` in the cache directory (your path might differ):

```bash
$ find out/cache/ -name pid.ll
out/cache/dd548827/common/kernel/pid.ll
```

4. Inspect the `.ll` file

```bash
$ head out/cache/dd548827/common/kernel/pid.ll

; ModuleID = 'common-mainline/common/kernel/pid.c'
source_filename = "common-mainline/common/kernel/pid.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i8:8:32-i16:16:32-i64:64-i128:128-n32:64-S128"
target triple = "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"

module asm "\09.section \22__ksymtab_strings\22,\22aMS\22,%progbits,1\09"
module asm "__kstrtab_init_pid_ns:\09\09\09\09\09"
module asm "\09.asciz \09\22init_pid_ns\22\09\09\09\09\09"
module asm "__kstrtabns_init_pid_ns:\09\09\09\09\09"
module asm "\09.asciz \09\22\22\09\09\09\09\09"
...
```

Hope that helps!